# passing a pointer of a node of singly linked list through function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
deleteNodeNoPointer(node) {
   node.val = node.next.val;
   node.next = node.next.next;
   return node;
}
```

How to pass the pointer of a node of singly linked list to that function

for example if first is the object of that class,
and we have the linked list

1->2->3->4->5->null;
and we have to send the pointer of the 3 to the function above..

```
first.deleteNodeNoPointer(---POINTER--OF--NODE 3--IN--SINGLYLINKEDLIST);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you have requires you pass in a reference to a node for deletion. So you would start from the head of the list and walk the list getting each nodes next node until you arrived at the one you wanted to delete. You would probably do this in a loop, until you found a node that met some condition, normally. But if you arbitrarily wanted to delete the third node, that would be `head.next.next`;

```js
class ListItem{
  constructor(val, next = null){
    this.val = val;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

/* work to make the list */
let head = new ListItem(1);
let cur = head;
for(let i = 2; i < 10; i++){
  cur.next = new ListItem(i);
  cur = cur.next;
}
/* prints the list for demo */
function printList(node){
  while(node != null){
    console.log(node.val);
    node = node.next;
  }
}

function deleteNodeNoPointer(node) {
   node.val = node.next.val;
   node.next = node.next.next;
   return node;
}

console.log('before deletion');
printList(head);//list is setup

let thirdNode = head.next.next;//get the third node
deleteNodeNoPointer(thirdNode);//remove the third node

console.log('after deletion');
printList(head);
```

Note that, if you actually have the head, deletion of a node from a list can be better achieved by assigning the `next` value of the parent of the deleted node, the value stored in the deleted node's `next`;

```
nodeBefore.next = nodeBefore.next.next;
```

Since the `deleteNodeNoPointer` function is kind of a hack around this approach, it presumes you don't have access to the parent node. Either way, you need a variable that holds a reference to the node for deletion and then pass it into the function.

Comment: So i can get the pointer by using this.head.next.next in javascript... I was actually wanted to do this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-a-linked-list-given-only-a-pointer-to-a-node-to-be-deleted-in-a-singly-linked-list-how-do-you-delete-it/